# How to encrypt a string into another string with length is 4 to 6

Tags: php, cryptography

I want to encrypt a string into another string with length is 4 to 6 for my SMS service.
For example, I want to encrypt UserID to the string xxxx.
So the users just text "MyPage xxxx" then send to my SMS service, I will decrypt the string xxx to know who send this message.

Thank you!

Comment: You could just generate a random string for each user in your database (preferably when their account is created). When someone requests `MyPage (key)`, you just lookup which user has that key.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can store 4-6 character unique string in your database and have your users to send it.

However, this raises some flags:

1. What if some other user learns this secret string and sends SMS with it? Would you trust such SMS that it was sent by user you have assumed? I don't think so.
2. If somebody is sending SMS to your server, presumably you will know their phone number where it was sent from - SMS will provide it. In that case, why bother asking user to provide anything more? Also, it is relatively difficult to forge sending SMS phone number. Don't get me wrong, sending phone number can be forged, but I think that it is still more secure than your approach.
3. Asking user to type anything that they need to remember is too much to ask. They will forget, they will make mistakes, they will screw it up. Don't do that, make it fully automatic, and just rely on sending phone number.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a random, 4 character identifier for each of your users (e.g. on registration) and store that in the database. Then, when you get the text, you can check for the identifier in the database and see who sent the message.